# Common Lisp appending package name to quoted keys in macros

Tags: package, common-lisp, symbols

I noticed the following behavior in Common Lisp (at least using SBCL), which I was able to reduce it to the following:

Suppose I have the following Macro:

```
(defpackage "MY-TEST"
  (:use "COMMON-LISP")
  (:export :appended
       :not-appended))

(in-package :MY-TEST)

(defmacro not-appended ()
  `(list ':type 'array))

(defmacro appended ()
  `(list ':type 'something-else))
```

The following is the output:

```
* (my-test:not-appended) 
(:TYPE ARRAY)


* (my-test:appended) 
(:TYPE MY-TEST::SOMETHING-ELSE)
```

Notice that in the second macro, the namespace is preceding the "SOMETHING-ELSE".

**Questions:**

- Why is t the case that they differ? Honestly I was expecting the behavior of the "not-appended" macro. Is that because "array" is somehow known to Common Lisp?
- If yes, then where can I find the other known keywords?

Comment: There is a symbol named `ARRAY` in the `COMMON-LISP`-package, which you imported. You can use `(apropos "" :cl)` to see all symbols in the package.

Comment: @jkiiski, thank you. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that this is fully unrelated to macros and is an effect of packages, symbols and how symbols are printed:

The package `MY-TEST':

```
CL-USER 2 > (defpackage "MY-TEST"
              (:use "COMMON-LISP")
              (:export :appended
               :not-appended))
#<The MY-TEST package, 0/16 internal, 2/16 external>
```

Making the package the current package by calling `in-package`:

```
CL-USER 3 > (in-package :MY-TEST)
#<The MY-TEST package, 0/16 internal, 2/16 external>
```

Let's compute a list of the symbols `array` and `foo`. See how the REPL prints it as `(ARRAY FOO)` because both symbols are accessible in package `MY-TEST`.

```
MY-TEST 4 > (list 'array 'foo)
(ARRAY FOO)
```

Making `CL-USER` the current package:

```
MY-TEST 5 > (in-package :cl-user)
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 151/256 internal, 0/4 external>
```

Now let's get the second last value and see how the REPL prints it:

```
CL-USER 6 > **
(ARRAY MY-TEST::FOO)
```

`ARRAY` is printed without package prefix, because it is the same symbol from the package `COMMON-LISP` (which was used in the package `MY-TEST`). `FOO` is printed with the package prefix `MY-TEST`, because it is an internal symbol in that package - it was interned there, because then the current package was `MY-TEST`. There are two colons, because the symbol `FOO` is not exported from the package `MY-TEST` and it is also not imported into the package `CL-USER`.

The package "CL" and "CL-USER" contain all the symbols from the programming language Common Lisp - thus importing "CL" into your own package makes all of those symbols available in that package, too.

```
CL-USER 7 > (let ((l '()))
              (do-symbols (sym (find-package "CL") l)
                (pushnew sym l)))
(MAKE-ARRAY INVOKE-DEBUGGER STRING-TRIM WILD-PATHNAME-P UNREAD-CHAR RESTART-BIND ...
```